# Display parent values when child filtered in Dax

Tags: excel, ssas, pivot-table, powerbi, dax

I have this table, [image]

and I want to display all the data of the clients who have the 'Campagne' A. So here is what I want :[image]

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the second table as a calculated table using the following:

```
TableA = FILTER(Table1,
             "A" IN CALCULATETABLE(
                        VALUES(Table1[Campagne]),
                        ALL(Table1),
                        Table1[Client] = EARLIER(Table1[Client])))
```

If you want a `True / False` calculated column on your original table, you can just use the conditional part of the above:

```
ClientA = "A" IN CALCULATETABLE(
                     VALUES(Table2[Campagne]),
                     ALL(Table2),
                     Table2[Client] = EARLIER(Table2[Client]))
```

What these are doing is taking the whole table (`ALL` line), filtering it to look at the `Client` in the current row (`EARLIER` line), and finding all the distinct `Campagne` associated with that `Client` any row (`VALUES` line) of this filtered table. Once we have those values, we check if "A" is a member.

Comment: I was trying to solve this myself and DaxStudio didn't recognise the IN function. This article implies it doesn't exist in DAX. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-in-and-exists/ however it clearly does!

Comment: @TDP It's a newer functionality. You should be able to use `CONTAINS` instead. Check out this article: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/the-in-operator-in-dax/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the code from the figure below, however you should add an extra column for this.

[image]

Comment: Actually I'm working in Power BI and I know I have to create a calculated column but can't find the right code. Regarding yours, it is not working because it's a code made for excel. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @MatRic, ok I see, hopefully someone can help you since I am not familiar with Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

The inner calculate is a filter where the client participated in Champagne A.  Using the filter, the outer calculate displays the table with the correct clients.

```
EVALUATE
CALCULATETABLE (
    Campaigne,
    CALCULATETABLE ( 
        DISTINCT ( Campaigne[Client] ), 
        Campaigne[Campagne] = "A" )
)
```